# Reverse a Generic Trimetric Projection

Tags: matrices, geometry, systems-of-equations, inverse, projection

[Trimetric Projected Tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3s4g.png)

I am creating a grid using Trimetric Projection tiles, and have a way to go from a standard 2D grid's coordinates to a generic Trimetric tile coordinate using the following equations:

```
HeightRatio = 0.5;               // Tiles are 128Hx256W, so height ratio is 1/2
HRI = 1/(2 * HeightRatio);       // I don't really know why this works, but it's a modified Inverse of HeightRatio
Skew = 0.565f;                   // Offset of top point to the left of center (For isometric this is 0)
MSkew = 1-Skew

TrimetricToFlat(TX, TY): //This converts trimetric grid coordinates (starting at origin) to flat grid 
        x = ((TX* MSkew) - ((1+Skew) * TY)) * HRI;
        y = (((1+Skew) * TX) + (TY* MSkew)) * 0.5f;
```

This all works as I want it, and given (0,0) to (N,N) trimetric grid positions I can generate a nice looking grid on a screen using the output x and y values. However, I want to be able to do the inverse and can't figure out how to do the system of equations for it.

The goal is to have a function similar like:

```
FlatToTrimetric(x, y):
    TX = ??
    TY = ??
```

Any help of guidance would be appriciated!

Comment: This is just two linear equations in two unknowns. Search for _solve system of linear equations_ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make this look a bit more mathematical by using

- $x$, $y$ for the projected (screen) coordinates
- $X$, $Y$ (instead of `TX`, `TY`) for the trimetric coordinates
- $S$ = `Skew`, $A$ = `HeightRatio`, and $V$ = `0.5` for vertical scaling.
- The horizontal scaling factor $H$ = `HRI` is actually $H = V / A$, i.e. vertical scaling factor divided by the height ratio.  (It makes geometric sense, if you think about it.)

This way, we can write the formula you use as
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x &= \biggl( (1 - S) H \biggr) X + \biggl( - (1 + S) H \biggr) Y \\
y &= \biggl( (1 + S) V \biggr ) X + \biggl( (1 - S) V \biggr) Y \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{1}\label{BtV1}$$

In linear algebra terms, if we use vectors $\vec{P} = (X, Y)$ and $\vec{p} = (x, y)$, we can express the above using a simple matrix $\mathbf{M}$:
$$\vec{p} = \mathbf{M} \vec{P}$$
where $$\mathbf{M} = \left[ \begin{matrix} H (1 - S) & - H (1 + S) \\
V (1 + S) & V (1 - S) \end{matrix} \right]$$

This means that
The inverse is
$$\vec{P} = \mathbf{M}^{-1} \vec{p}$$
where the inverse of matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is
$$\mathbf{M}^{-1} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\frac{1 - S}{2 H (S^2 + 1)} & \frac{1 + S}{2 V (S^2 + 1)} \\
-\frac{1 + S}{2 H (S^2 + 1)} & \frac{1 - S}{2 V (S^2 + 1)} \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$

In Cartesian coordinates, that is equivalent to
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
X &= \biggl(\frac{1 - S}{2 H (S^2 + 1)} \biggr) x + \biggl(\frac{1 + S}{2 V (S^2 + 1)}\biggr) y \\
Y &= \biggl(-\frac{1 + S}{2 H (S^2 + 1)} \biggr) x + \biggl(\frac{1 - S}{2 V (S^2 + 1)}\biggr) y \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{2}\label{BtV2}$$

---

Note how I grouped the terms in (larger) parentheses in $\eqref{BtV1}$ and $\eqref{BtV2}$, above.  This is because you can do both mappings using the same code, say in pseudocode:

```
Function Map(x, y, Cxx, Cxy, Cyx, Cyy):
    Let newX = x * Cxx + y * Cxy
    Let newY = x * Cyx + y * Cyy
    Return newX, newY
End Function
```

In the original mapping, the four constants are obviously

```
    Cxx = (1 - S) * H
    Cxy = -(1 + S) * H
    Cyx = (1 + S) * V
    Cyy = (1 - S) * V
```

and in the reverse mapping,

```
    Cxx = (1 - S) / (2 * H * (S * S + 1))
    Cxy = (1 + S) / (2 * V * (S * S + 1))
    Cyx = -(1 + S) / (2 * H * (S * S + 1))
    Cyy = (1 - S) / (2 * V * (S * S + 1))
```

These four (eight, if you count both ways) only change if `H`, `V`, or `S` changes, so you can simply precalculate them into global variables, and use the pseudocode to very efficiently calculate either way, using just four multiplications and two additions per point.

---

The reason for how and why this works, exactly, is the matrix $\mathbf{M}$.  In it, the left column is the new $x$ axis vector, and right column is the new $y$ axis vector.  (The same applies to the inverse matrix, and all such matrices in both 2D and 3D, too.)

Trimetric projection is one of [oblique projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection), where the third coordinate ($z$ axis) is always directly up, and $x$ and $y$ axes are at different angles with respect to vertical.  (I happen to use -1:2 and 2:1 quite often, i.e. `Cxx = -0.5, Cxy = 2, Cyx = 2, Cyy = 0.5`, which you get with `S=0.6, A=-1, V=5/17≃0.2941`.)

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much for the solution as well as explaining how it worked.
Implemented the formulas in code and it works perfectly :)